# tensorflow inception v3 transfer learning

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, image-recognition

I'd like to use tensorflow's trained inception model to classify flower photos.
By loading `tensorflow_inception_graph.pb`, I imported two tensors from the graph:`pool_3/_reshape:0` and `DecodeJpeg/contents:0`

```
bottleneck_tensor_name='pool_3/_reshape:0'
jpeg_data_tensor_name='DecodeJpeg/contents:0'
model_dir='C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/Neural_Network'
model_file='tensorflow_inception_graph.pb'
    with gfile.FastGFile(os.path.join(model_dir,model_file),'rb') as f:
        graph_def=tf.GraphDef()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
    bottleneck_tensor,jpeg_data_tensor=tf.import_graph_def(graph_def,return_elements=[bottleneck_tensor_name,jpeg_data_tensor_name])
```

After loading my own `image_data`, I performed:

```
bottleneck_values=sess.run(bottleneck_tensor,{image_data_tensor:image_data})
bottleneck_values=np.squeeze(bottleneck_values)
```

However, I got two types of errors: (1) BatchNormalization Deprecated (2) shape is incompatible.

Is it because `jpeg_data_tensor_name`'s shape from the graph is different from my photo's shape? Where can I get the source code to check how `pool_3/_reshape:0` and `DecodeJpeg/contents:0` are specified?

If BatchNormalization is deprecated, need to retrain from scratch?

```
2018-02-25 20:42:07.519912: W C:\tf_jenkins\workspace\rel-win\M\windows\PY\36\tensorflow\core\framework\op_def_util.cc:343] Op BatchNormWithGlobalNormalization is deprecated. It will cease to work in GraphDef version 9. Use tf.nn.batch_normalization().
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1350, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1329, in _run_fn
    status, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py", line 473, in __exit__
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [5] vs. [700]
     [[Node: evaluation_1/Equal = Equal[T=DT_INT64, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](evaluation_1/ArgMax, evaluation_1/ArgMax_1)]]
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 36, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 895, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1128, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1344, in _do_run
    options, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1363, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [5] vs. [700]
     [[Node: evaluation_1/Equal = Equal[T=DT_INT64, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](evaluation_1/ArgMax, evaluation_1/ArgMax_1)]]
Caused by op 'evaluation_1/Equal', defined at:
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.2.4\helpers\pydev\pydevconsole.py", line 542, in <module>
    pydevconsole.start_server(host, int(port), int(client_port), client_host)
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.2.4\helpers\pydev\pydevconsole.py", line 366, in start_server
    process_exec_queue(interpreter)
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.2.4\helpers\pydev\pydevconsole.py", line 221, in process_exec_queue
    more = interpreter.add_exec(code_fragment)
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.2.4\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_console_utils.py", line 251, in add_exec
    more = self.do_add_exec(code_fragment)
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.2.4\helpers\pydev\pydevconsole.py", line 123, in do_add_exec
    command.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.2.4\helpers\pydev\pydevconsole.py", line 82, in run
    self.more = self.interpreter.runsource(text, '<input>', symbol)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\code.py", line 75, in runsource
    self.runcode(code)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\code.py", line 91, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 20, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_math_ops.py", line 1700, in equal
    "Equal", x=x, y=y, name=name)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3160, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1625, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Incompatible shapes: [5] vs. [700]
     [[Node: evaluation_1/Equal = Equal[T=DT_INT64, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](evaluation_1/ArgMax, evaluation_1/ArgMax_1)]]
```

Comment: You might check precisely the shapes taht you are manipulating as `Incompatible shapes: [5] vs. [700]` shows clearly there's a mismatch in your data structure. The batch normalization deprecated shouldn't be a problem. Note that in machine learning the data preparation is really something critical, especially if you want to use transfer learning.

Comment: Will 'jpeg_data_tensor_name' from the graph have already-specified shape which is incompatible with my image's shape? Since I don't have the source code of the pb file, I don't know the tensor shape that I'm importing from the graph

Comment: It's not necessary the image dimension that doesn't match. It can be the way your data is structured. You should start by playing with the original example and understand how it is architectured before trying to transfer it to another problem. It seems that it is a tensorflow tutorial based on jupyter notebooks so you might find everything to learn how it works.